# how to get file date and time (Timestamp) from a file on sd card with SD.h?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, sd-card

i want to get the date and time (Timestamp) of a specific file on sd card. 
How can i do this?

I use the sd.h and can not use any other like SdFat.h

Comment: an old version of SdFat is under the hood of the SD library. the wrapper classes don't make the timestamp accessible. you would have to open the file SdFat way and then process it as in `ls` function in SdFile.cpp